# How to select till the sum reach some value

Tags: mysql, sql

having this table

```
#table stock
+-------+----------+
|  id   |   stock  |
+-------+----------+
|   1   |    20    |
+-------+----------+
|   2   |    25    |
+-------+----------+
|   3   |    10    |
+-------+----------+
|   4   |    20    |
+-------+----------+
#note: this is an arbitrary random data
```

How can I keep selecting rows from the table till the `sum()` of the stock column reaches some value or a *little higher* , and the table is `ORDER BY id ASC`.

For example I want to select rows from the table till I have sum of stock **'50'** , so the result will be

```
#result 3 rows
+-------+----------+
|  id   |   stock  |
+-------+----------+
|   1   |    20    |
+-------+----------+
|   2   |    25    |
+-------+----------+
|   3   |    10    |
+-------+----------+
```

the sum of stock now is '55' which is the closest possible higher value than '50' , and if we take the next row `id:4` the sum of stock will be higher than 50 , and if we remove the row `id:3` the value will be 45 which is less than the stock I want 50 .

I can achieve this with PHP by selecting all the rows and loop throw them, but I guess that will be a waste. **Is there a possible way to do that on a lower level and let mysql do that for me by a `sql` query?**

*Thank you and forgive me if I messed something , I'm new to programming*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a cumulative sum for this to work.  One method uses variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@sum := @sum + stock) as cume_stock
      from t cross join
           (select @sum := 0) params
      order by id 
     ) t
where cume_stock < 50 or (cume_stock >= 50 and cume_stock - stock < 50);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time sir. BTW your name gave me the feeling of *"Without thinking, that is what I was trying to do"*

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you again but I'm getting a syntax error  *"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') t
 where cume_stock < 50 or (cume_stock >= 50 and cume_stock - stock < 50)' at line 6 0.000 sec"*

Comment: I moved the join clause before the order clause for the sub query `"from t cross join (select @sum := 0) params order by id"` and the syntax error is gone . is that going to give me the same correct result ?